MariaDB incorrectly updating sequence?
Original question:
In 11.4.3-MariaDB I have this very simple sequence: CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq START WITH 1; (My SQL client says it uses InnoDB) and I noticed an issue with it.
I created the query below to be able to reserve several values of a sequence, but it returns nothing and apparently, only 4 values are consumed each time (checked using SELECT NEXTVAL(test_seq);, vs 50 expected.
WITH Seq(Value) AS (
    SELECT nextval(test_seq) FROM seq_1_to_50
)
SELECT VALUE AS LowerBound,
   (
        SELECT MIN(Value)
        FROM Seq Top
        WHERE Value >= Bottom.Value
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Seq WHERE Value = Top.Value + 1)
    ) AS UpperBound
FROM Seq Bottom
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Seq WHERE Value = Bottom.Value - 1)

Regarding that:

The query is designed to skip contiguous values and thus decrease the network load. This is what makes it complicated.
Of course, I could just run the code from the CTE's body (SELECT nextval(test_seq) FROM seq_1_to_50); doing that does work but I do not see a valid reason for the complete query only increment the sequence by 4 with no rows returned.If optimization was the cause, I could understand the sequence not being incremented at all, just not that behavior.
I am more of an expert of Postgres than MariaDB, so I could test an equivalent of the above in Postgres with the slightly modified query here (the only difference is the code inside the CTE):

WITH Seq(Value) AS (
    SELECT nextval('test_seq') FROM generate_series(1, 50)
)
SELECT VALUE AS LowerBound,
   (
        SELECT MIN(Value)
        FROM Seq Top
        WHERE Value >= Bottom.Value
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Seq WHERE Value = Top.Value + 1)
        ) AS UpperBound
FROM Seq Bottom
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Seq WHERE Value = Bottom.Value - 1)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Since it seemed this question was not understood as self-contained by some people, I have created this SQL fiddle that demonstrates the issue. Feel free to visit the URL and see for yourself.
While I was at it, I added a query to show how SELECT COUNT(*) returns inconsistent results when in a subquery.

This goes against what their documentation describes. Studying the documentation read more than one sentence... The result returned by SETVAL() is next_value or NULL if the given next_value and round is smaller than the current value.

In any case, first things should be to extract a [mcve] and, if the behaviour violates the documentation, file a bug report.

@Akina: Sorry, I have indeed missed a sentence. I am going to plead being tired for that mistake, as it took me reading the 2nd example block (labelled SETVAL setting higher and lower values on a sequence with an increment of 10:) another 2x to realize the example given with a lower value was returning NULL and not 50 like I thought I had read the first 2 times. I must be squinting my eyes more than I thought.

@UlrichEckhardt: with the sequence definition and the query (which does not depend on the content of a table/an index so the query plan is not included), what do you think is missing? I genuinely believe this is a MRE: the code reproduces the issue on that version of MariaDB + being 1 query to create the sequence and 1 query to try and use it, it is minimal. I do not know who voted to close the question asking for debugging details but I do not see how I could possibly fulfill that level of requirement...

I browsed pages about optimizations but I can't find a possible explanation. To the best of my knowledge, nothing in the documentation says I should expect a sequence to increment by 4 here (Had it been 0, I could have thought about table elimination but 4 really looks like it comes out of nowhere + it does not explain why the main query returns no record). Of course, proving an inexistence is another impossible standard so I cannot do it -> Hence my reason for asking someone more expert about MariaDB.

If you want to reset the sequence then you must use ALTER SEQUENCE

I think that seq_1_to_50 and CREATE SEQUENCE are two different, unconnected features.

That does not answer the question though. seq_1_to_50 is only used to call nextval('test_seq') more than once. The fact that they are unrelated feature does not justify it working when executed as an independent query and not working when executed inside the CTE of a bigger query or if it does, then why?

I do currently vote to close this due to lack of info. Point is, if I just start an empty DB (e.g. using Docker), I can't reproduce this with the given info. First, I have to create and select a DB. Then, it seems I have to create a table, but at that point I don't want to guess. I'd say it's your responsibility to first isolate the issue, so you would already have the required SQL code. And, if you don't, how do you know it's not something unrelated, perhaps in the global setup that you already forgot about that you changed it?

@UlrichEckhardt And may I know what table you think must be created? The fact you believe there is one just shows you were wrong with your close vote. To run the example, you have to create the sequence as instructed in the question, then run the query I claim does not return the right result. Nothing seems missing to me.

You might have guessed it, it was ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'foo.test_seq' doesn't exist. foo is the name of the DB I used for that, then I just dumped the first snippet of code on it that you provided. Sigh. I'm out here...

@UlrichEckhardt: First sentence in my question, hence actual first snippet I provided: "In 11.4.3-MariaDB I have this very simple sequence: CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq START WITH 1;". Does not look to me it could possibly cause the DBMS to complain about a table named test_seq not existing... The SQLfiddle provided in the edit works just as is.
